# linker option while building vmlinux

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, archlinux, archlinux-arm

I am understanding how vmlinux will create with the help of link-vmlinux.sh script, I could see it is passing -p option to the linker while building vmlinux, but I couldn't see any option named -p when executed linker with --help.

```
#arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld -EL -p --no-undefined -X --build-id -o vmlinux
```

Can you please tel me what is the use of '-p' option in the above command.

Answer (score 0):

I reckon it prints the program headers object file format uses also known as
segments.The program headers describe how the program should be loaded into memory. You can print them out by using the objdump program with the  -p option.

Did you try `arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld --help` ?

Comment: yes I tried with "arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld --help", but I couldn't see any option with -p. I could see only " -P AUDITLIB, --depaudit=AUDITLIB"